# Matlab: Inserting a diagonal into an odd matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Hey so I have a 22x23 matrix and I'm trying to insert a diagonal of NaNs straight through it, thus making it 23x23. I've been trying different one liners but I'm starting to think it might have to be some sort of loop. I'm looking for the following type of output:

```
NaN #  #  #  #  #...
 # NaN #  #  #  #...
 #  # NaN #  #  #...
... ... etc.
```

Where # is an existing value in the 22x23 matrix.
Any insight into this would be helpful, I feel like I'm chasing my tail a bit here.

Comment: Try a loop. Show us your code.

Comment: If you're "inserting" these `NaN` values, wouldn't the dimensions become `23 x 24`?  You're introducing one new column for each row.  It would also help if you should a small numerical example too.  What you ultimately want in the end is a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

One line is hard, but maybe two lines is ok?

```
A = rand(22,23); % put your matrix here
B = [zeros(1,23); tril(A)] + [triu(A); zeros(1,23)];  % separate upper and lower triangles
B(1:24:23^2) = NaN;  %% simple linear index for populating diagonal
```

Comment: Pretty much what I was going to write. +1... now to think of another solution :)